# IMAP library not found in my robot framework script

Tags: robotframework, imaplib

I have successfully installed IMAP library for robot framework but still showing me error as 'Import file not found'.

I am using Pycharm editor for robot framework to create scripts also intellibot plugin is installed.

Currently I am trying to run example script which is on 'https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-imaplibrary' URL.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5njl.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Take the time to properly copy, paste, and format the code into the question.

Comment: I agree with @BryanOakley and would like to add that at the very least not link to an image but put it in the question. Few are going to take the effort to click it.

Answer (score 0):

after running 'Pip list' is this library listed there?
if yes press ctrl+1 in that line and verify if library is added in red.xml file.

If not uninstall and install it again